# How do i deal with proftpd message "error setting IPV6_V6ONLY: Protocol not available" in auth.log?

Tags: ftp, logging, proftpd

I get lots of errormessages in my `/var/log/auth.log` in this form:

```
myserver.de (::ffff:11.22.33.44[::ffff:11.22.33.44]) - error setting IPV6_V6ONLY: Protocol not available
```

How should I deal with these?

Should I enable IPV6 somewhere? or should I suppress these messages somehow?

(I am using debian-squeeze)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have IPv6 disabled completely in the OS. Unless you want to use IPv6 you don't need to worry about it. If you want to stop the error message from appearing you can [disable IPv6 support](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_UseIPv6.html) with `UseIPv6 off` in the configuration or the `--ipv4` command line option.

Comment: Or fix whatever configuration problem is causing IPv6 to not be available.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Which may be intentional.